# Jquery fading images with lazy loader for multiple slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loader, lazy-evaluation

I have used stackoverflow for the past year and has really helped for design, this is the first time im truely stuck and I really dont have a clue have to do this...

I have a website im building which has 60 items on a page with thumbs, On mouseover I want the thumb to to change to 5 other img like a fast slideshow, using lazy loader so the alternative img's don't load until mouseover

I have just started learning Javascript and Jquery in my spare time, and unfortuantely this is way beyond my capabilities :(

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/razzabazza17/hRErs/ but this is just to load when scrolling what I need is this to overflow: hidden; around the container then when mouse over on primary img it will flick through the other 4 thumbs in sequence. It also need to stop this function when stop on mouseover.

I appreciate any help or advice you can give, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Human capabilities (so as human stupidity) goes beyond imagination. Never give up learning new stuff

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this jQuery plugin? 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
Sounds like it's what you are after, the implementation looks pretty simple